# Ask user for information and return that information

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to ask the user to enter their name and then return; "Hello and their name". I know its something simple that I am missing, but I just dont know what it is.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {

        NSString * name = @"";

        NSLog(@"What is your name?");
        scanf("%@", &name);

        NSLog(@"Hello %@",name);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to mix Objective-C and C here.  This is somewhat tricky to do, but let me see if I can help point you the right direction.

First, change:

```
NSString * name = @"";
scanf("%@", &name);
```

to:

```
char name[64];
scanf("%s", &name);
```

and see if that works better.

[`scanf` is a C function that works with c types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf_format_string), and NSString is an objective C object which doesn't really work with "`scanf`".

(The "64" means that there's enough buffer space for 64 characters and if you blow past that, the app will likely crash).

Also, change:

```
NSLog(@"Hello %@",name);
```

to this:

```
NSLog(@"Hello %s",name);
```

As "`%s`" in the format tells NSLog that you're passing a C-style string and not a NSString object.

Answer (score 0):

You're using an NSString object in C, which doesn't work. `scanf` expects a C string. Here's an example:

```
NSLog(@"What is your name?");
char name[40];
scanf("%s", name);
NSLog(@"Hello %@",[NSString stringWithCString:name encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

Or you can stay 100% in C:

```
printf("What is your name?");
char name[40];
scanf("%s", name);
printf("Hello %s", name);
```